# Object that follows object

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I want to implement a function in which one object follows a moving object in C++. Any tips how to do that will be of great help to me.

Comment: That's quite vague, do you want to elaborate?

Comment: Object, as in OOP? or object as in a circle on your screen? Or something else entirely?

Comment: You have to give more information. What object, physical through a camera? Sounds like you are in the wrong forum...

Comment: It's an object on my screen, Isaac. :)

Comment: OK, I have done this, but I needed to do completely different approach to this, otherwise it would be really hard to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This excellent post states, and I quote from it:

> The player's position is point1. Enemy's position is point2. First
>   you'll need to find the difference between the x1 and x2 and y1 and y2
>   (I'll call these xd and yd). Then you can get the angle between the
>   two points by doing theta = atan(yd/xd). Now you should be able to get
>   the new x and y (which I will call x3 and y3) by using the angle and
>   the distance you want to travel where x3 = (d)(cos(theta)) and y3 =
>   (d)(sin(theta)). Move the enemy to (x3, y3).
>
> d is the speed the enemy is moving per update. You might have to mess
>   with the signs to get the directions right (i.e. if the enemy moves in
>   the correct x direction but wrong y direction then change the sign on
>   y).

More here : [Game enemy move towards player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625021/game-enemy-move-towards-player)

Comment: Nice Michael, this is almost the same solution that I implemented, except I was doing with acos to lower the number of my variables. ;) Thanks, and I will rate this as a best answer.

Comment: This assumes the player to be stationary. Besides, all this trig is unnecessary; Isaac Fife describes the proper computation.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the movement should happen. It's impossible to get a common answer. For map with fixed nodes (or a simple chess board like grid), use a pathfinding algorithm such as A*.

For open/free movement you'd most likely want to turn your objects (or it's movement vector) towards the target and then accelerate/deaccelerate it.

But without further details it's impossible to give any perfect answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Mario. As for the concern of my Q., I implemented free movement, without vectors, xy positioning movement. Any tips for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Using just x and y, this is a pretty simple vector problem.

Use a unit vector for direction. Multiply this by a scalar for the distance you want the follower to travel in one unit of time. This will give you your new relative position. The unit vector should be in the direction pointing from the follower to the leader.