# Issue with GLKVector2's

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

I'm having trouble setting up vectors for an object in my code. I tried modeling my code similarly to the answer in this question: [Game enemy move towards player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625021/game-enemy-move-towards-player) except that I'm using GLKVector2's. I thought my implementation seemed correct, but it's really only my first time using vectors with GLKit and in general I haven't used them too much before.

My current code looks something like:

```
GLKVector2 vector = GLKVector2Make(self.player.position.x - self.target.position.x, self.player.position.y - self.target.position.y);

    float hypo = sqrt(vector.x*vector.x + vector.y*vector.y);
    float speed = 0.25;

    vector = GLKVector2Make(vector.x/hypo, vector.y/hypo);
    vector = GLKVector2MultiplyScalar(vector, speed);

    GLKVector2 sum = GLKVector2Add(vector, self.target.position);

    self.target.moveVelocity = sum;
```

Is it possible that my logic just isn't correct here? I'd appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!

EDIT: just for clarification since I didn't really explain what happens.. Basically the "enemy" shapes either stutter/jump or just stick. They aren't moving toward the other object at all.

EDIT 2:

If I try using GLKVector2Normalize, then nothing moves. If I do something like:

```
GLKVector2 vector = GLKVector2Make(self.player.position.x - self.target.position.x, self.player.position.y - self.target.position.y);

    float speed = 0.10;
//    float distance = GLKVector2Distance(self.player.position, self.target.position);

//    vector = GLKVector2Normalize(vector);
    vector = GLKVector2MultiplyScalar(vector, speed);
    self.target.moveVelocity = vector;
```

Then the movement works toward the player object, but only updates the one time even though it should be updating every second.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- There's no need to calculate the magnitude of the vector and divide yourself -- GLKit has a `GLKVector2Normalize` function, which takes a vector and returns the vector in the same direction with length 1. You can then use `GLKVector2MultiplyScalar` (as you do) to change the speed.
- Your target's velocity should be set to vector, not sum, assuming that in the target's update method (which you should call once per timestep), you add `self.moveVelocity.x` to `self.position.x` and `self.moveVelocity.y` to `self.position.y` each timestep. As it is now, your `sum` variable will hold the *position* that your target should have one timestep in the future, not its velocity.

Comment: I updated my question. Something is still not working properly. I think my update code is fine, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: Can you post your update code? You should be incrementing `position.x` by `moveVelocity.x * timeSinceLastUpdate` and `position.y` by `moveVelocity.y * timeSinceLastUpdate` before drawing to the screen each time step. Not sure why GLKVector2Normalize wouldn't be working.